# Как мне сделать закрытие модального окна?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я сделал свою модальное окно, типо alert под свои нужды, только такой момент, мне нужно реализовать если кликнуть по области который не заходит модального окна то она бы закрывалась. В принципе как обычное модальное окно сделать при закрытие. То есть там или при нажатие на кнопку или кликнуть по области за модальном окном. Вот это нужно мне реализовать. Удаление объекта мне не помогло
Сейчас он закрывается когда нажать на нет
Вот мои пример https://jsfiddle.net/hollanditkzn/nwajvdrr/43/

```js
$('li.list-group-item').hover(function(){
 $(this).append($('<a href="#" class="delete">Удалить</a>'));
}, function(){
 $(this).find('a:last').remove();
})

$('body').on('click', 'a',function(e){
 console.log('Hello world')
 let div=document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'modal-body'
  div.onclick = function(e){
    var t=e?e.target:window.event.srcElement;
    if(t.tagName=='INPUT'){
      t.value=='Да' && console.log('yes');
      this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    }
  }
  div.innerHTML='<div><h1>Уверены</h1><br/><p>Что хотите удалить?</p><div><input type="button" class="delete-button" value="Да"><input type="button" value="Нет">'
    return document.body.appendChild(div);
})
$('.modal-body').click(function(){
 this.remove();
})
```

```css
.modal-body{
  text-align:left;
  padding: 19% 32% 103px 34%;
  color: white;
  position:fixed;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  top:0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.45);
  margin-right:-100px;
  margin-bottom:-20px;
  display:block;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 1;
}

h1{
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
p{
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
input{
  font-size: 13px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 158px;
  height: 42px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
input:hover{
  background: rgba(49, 41, 39, 0.5);
}
.delete-button:hover{
  border: 2px solid #ff6666;
  color: #ff6666;
}
.delete-button:active{
  color: #ffffff;
  border-color: #ff6666;
  background: rgba(255, 102, 102, 0.5);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 15px rgba(49, 41, 39, 0.4);
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".modal-body");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        container.hide();
    }
});
```

ES6

```
const hideModal = () => {
 const $modalSel = document.querySelector('.modal-body');

 document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
   if (!e.target.classList.contains('modal-body')) {  
      $modalSel.style.display = 'none';
   }
 });
};
```